# Septic problem!

Tags: septic

We have an issue with our septic pipe I guess or something else. Our septic tank is in the backyard and we had that pumped not to long ago. The problem arises when we shower, run the dishwasher, or washing machine sewer smelling water runs up from the ground in the front yard and down the sidewalk. What can cause this???

Comment: Opposite side of the house? Perhaps that's the leach field, and it's failing? (Doesn't seem likely...)

Comment: Well when the plumber ran a camera up the pipe there was another box under our stairs and there are a few bushes in the front around the box so maybe roots?!?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry in advance. I just happened by & I haven't seen all the septic designs out there or had a septic system in 20-years. It sounds like a leach field outlet blockage or clog, check the manhole or observation pipe for signs & smells of leakage.

Maybe you have an overflow pipe (which I've never heard of) or much worse, that you're still connected to an old leach field. The only other reason would be an overflow from your surface penetrations in the back yard that are just following the landscape's natural drainage & may only appear to be bubbling up.

Comment: Thank you!! It may actually be a leach field failure like roots or a broken line...

Comment: That's what I would suspect & definitely get it cleared, camera viewed & fixed if needed. Maybe a guest flushed something they shouldn't have before or after the tank pumping.

Comment: Well after speaking with my brother we believe whoever put it in or something along that line may have have butt did the job!! He dug up a little where the "water" was coming up in the flower bed and the pipe stops right at the sidewalk and it's completely smashed

Comment: That would explain that. But, is it an overflow pipe or something else highly unusual that runs all the way out to the front yard?

Comment: Well we have no clue!! Lol. The pipe looks like something you'd put on the end of a gutter drain on your house. We just know it seems to be draining sewer smelling water.

Comment: Yeah, that ain't right. It's got to be a downspout drain line that's connected to the septic system to help with keeping the system flushed & diluted. It may need to be disconnected from the septic, as it may not be at all legal.

Comment: Thanks for the advice/help!! I'm gonna tell him we need to get right on fixing that before the neighbors start complaining about the smell and it running down our sidewalk/driveway